# (Python) How to extract elements between parentheses from a spliced list

Tags: python, list, parentheses

So I was doing a PEMDAS calculator and I managed to do everything but the parenthesis so my question is how to extract from a list like this :
`r = ["4","+","2","(","2","+","5",")"]`

["2","+","5"]

and to clarify it more if the code was like this:
`r = ["4","+","2","(","2","+","5",")","+","(","2","+","5",")"]`

this should be the output
["2","+","5","2","+","5"]

Comment: pemdas calculator?

Comment: you should describe the criterium/law to fetch such terms... otherwise just  slice the list `''.join(r[4:7])` (which I guess is not what you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to extract data between parenthesis. so you have a list which contain the data you want.

```
r = ["4","+","2","(","2","+","5",")"]
r_new = []
for i in range(len(r)):
    if r[i] == "(":
        i=i+1
        for j in range(len(r)-i):
            if(r[i+j]==")"):
                print(r_new)
                break
            else:
                r_new.append(r[i+j])
```

Comment: thanks for this, I have been trying to do this for a long time. However, this is will work if I only have one parentheses in the list what if the code was like this `r = ["4","+","2","(","2","+","5",")","+","(","2","+","5",")"]`

Comment: use the pop() method to remove the data which you save in new list from the old list and try the for loop again for the other parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be workable for you?

```
r = ['4', '+', '2', '(', '2', '+', '5', ')', '+', '(', '2', '+', '5', ')']

index = [x for x,y in enumerate(r) if y == '(' or y == ')']

grouped_index = [[index[i*2],index[i*2+1]] for i in range(int(len(index)/2))]

grouped_value = [r[i[0]+1:i[1]] for i in grouped_index]

sum(grouped_value, [])

['2', '+', '5', '2', '+', '5']
```